# Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: util.kalyan.HelloGoogleMapsActivity

Tags: android

I have included all the necessary fields correctly.
But still, I am not able to launch the Google map on my emulator.
Checked the internet permissions also.
Getting error like:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(2064): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity 
ComponentInfo{util.kalyan/util.kalyan.HelloGoogleMapsActivity}: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: util.kalyan.HelloGoogleMapsActivity
```

Please find below my code.

**HelloGoogleMapsActivity.java**

```
package util.kalyan;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import util.kalyan.R;
public class HelloGoogleMapsActivity extends MapActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    }    
    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"      package="util.kalyan"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"></uses-library>
    <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity android:name=".HelloGoogleMapsActivity"    android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-  permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

Any one please help me in this at the earliest.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Change the android:name in activity definition

from

```
<activity android:name=".HelloGoogleMapsActivity" ../>
```

to

```
<activity android:name="util.kalyan.HelloGoogleMapsActivity" ../>
```

Comment: I have tried this. I am getting error like " Could not find Could not find HelloGoogleMaps.apk! "

Comment: I have finally resolved the issue. The mistake is I have placed " <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"></uses-library> " tag outside the application tag in AndroidManifest.xml. So issue is resolved when I placed inside the application tag. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

You emulator target should be one that includes **Google APIs (Google Inc.)**.

Comment: I have crated  a new AVD with target as Google API only. But still facing the same issue.

Comment: W/dalvikvm(793): Unable to resolve superclass of Lutil/kalyan/HelloGoogleMapsActivity; (3)
W/dalvikvm(793): Link of class 'Lutil/kalyan/HelloGoogleMapsActivity;' failed
D/AndroidRuntime(793): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(793): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409951f8)
E/AndroidRuntime(793): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(793): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{util.kalyan/util.kalyan.HelloGoogleMapsActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: util.kalyan.HelloGoogleMapsActivity

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your HelloGoogleMapsActivity class > BuildPath > Exclude Then Right click on your HelloGoogleMapsActivity class > BuildPath > Include your class again